# Send SMS using Android number using command line

Tags: android, command, prompt

Is it possible to send SMS using command prompt from a PC via my Android phone?(The PC is preferably a Mac)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with ADB (Android Debug Bridge)?

1. Install ADB from [here](https://wiki.lineageos.org/adb_fastboot_guide.html)
2. After extracting the ADB Tool and opening your Command Prompt use the following commands:

   ```
   adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.SENDTO -d sms:CCXXXXXXXXXX --es sms_body "SMS BODY GOES HERE" --ez exit_on_sent true
   adb shell input keyevent 22
   adb shell input keyevent 66
   ```

It is not guaranteed that this will work, because you may need to find the correct keyevent values to pass. But it's worth a shot.